# RevTex template downloaded from Overleaf won't compile

Tags: templates, overleaf, revtex, journal-publishing

I am writing a journal article for submission to Review of Scientific Instruments (AIP Publishing). Their officially supported method of writing in LaTeX is using Overleaf. I was going to be away from an internet connection for an extended period of time, so wanted to download the LaTeX document for working offline.

I navigated to this website, opened as a template, then went to the menu and downloaded the source zipped folder.
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submission-to-aip-publishing-journals/xhsskcchtbxf

Upon opening the aiptemplate.tex file and attempting to compile, I get the following error message:

`File 'aps12pt4-1.rtx' not found. ...intsize\expandafter{\@pointsize@default}`

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Some AIP journals (including RSI) still use RevTeX 4.1, this is why we have both templates available on Overleaf. If you saw an error about aps12pt4-1.rtx not found when compiling locally, you may need to install the revtex4-1 package using your TeX distribution's package manager: https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Overleaf (or AIP Publishing) needs to update their template. The package revtex4-1 is no longer contained in some tex packages, so the change was as simple as changing this line:

`\documentclass[aip,graphicx]{revtex4-1}`

to

`\documentclass[aip,graphicx]{revtex4-2}`

Overleaf also recognizes revtex4-2, so you're safe to change this on the version in Overleaf as well.

Comment: Erh, revtex4-1 is no longer in miktex, but according to tan texlive still provides it